# Generating .cpp and.h file from ..qml file in qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, qml

How to generate a .cpp and .h file for login.qml file?

I have written a .qml file for a login page.

my code is as following

import QtQuick 1.0

```
Rectangle{
    id:screen
    color: "lightgray"
    width: 3000; height:2700

    Column {
        id: column1
        width: 201
        height: 400

        Row {
            id: row1
            width: 40
            height:50

            TextInput {
                id: userName
                x: 40
                y: 18
                width: 80
                height: 20
                text: qsTr("UserName")
                font.pixelSize: 12
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: rectangle1
                x: 115
                y: 18
                width: 80
                height: 20
                color: "#ffffff"
            }


        }

        Row {
            id: row2
            width: 40
            height: 50

            TextInput {
                id: password
                x: 40
                y: 18
                width: 80
                height: 20
                text: qsTr("Password")
                font.pixelSize: 12
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: rectangle2
                x: 115
                y: 18
                width: 80
                height: 20
                color: "#ffffff"
            }
        }

        Row {
            id: row3
            x: 8
            y: 113
            width: 40
            height: 50

            Rectangle {
                id: rectangle3
                x: 8
                y: 8
                width: 80
                height: 20
                color: "#ffffff"

            Text {
                    id: login
                    text: "Login"
                    x:4
                    y:4
                    width:30
                    height:10
                    font.pixelSize: 12
                }

                   }

        }



    }

    MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                myclass.doStuffFromQmlSlot();

                Qt.quit();
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: `import QtQuick 1.0` --> what Qt & Qt Creator version is that? QtQuick 1 was deprecated in Qt 5. There probably is a "Qt Quick Application" project template in your Qt Creator (at least there is in newer versions, not sure about older ones), just create one and replace the QML that is there (potentially changing the main.cpp to load your file instead), then you can build an actual executable for your code.

Comment: Why do you want to do that ?
In the Qt Enterprise edition there's a Qt Quick Compiler that compiles qml files to c++ transparently.

Answer (score 0):

That would be quite some work.

You would need to write a C++ code generator or find an existing one.

You would either need to parse the QML code or load it and traverse the tree to feed your code generator.

Your generated code would then either depend on private Qt headers or you need your own implementations for the QtQuick types.